# IOC and Silverlight

Tags: c#, .net, silverlight, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control

In mvc asp.net, I can override a factory to create my controllers, and so put a reference to my IOC just here. Doing So every interface needed by the constructor of my controllers will be feeded by my IOC .

Is there some common way to do it using Silverlight?
At the moment I only found to use the kernel of Ninject everywhere :

```
public partial class MyUserControlSL   
{
    public MyUserControlSL()
    {
        DataContext = new MyViewModel(Kernel.Get<IMyRepository>());
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

eg using StructureMap and MVC:

```
public class ControllerFactory : DefaultControllerFactory
{
    protected override IController GetControllerInstance(
        RequestContext requestContext, Type controllerType)
    {
        IController result = null;
        try
        {
            if (controllerType != null)
            {
                result = ObjectFactory.GetInstance(controllerType) 
                    as Controller;
            }
            else
            {
                return base.GetControllerInstance(
                    requestContext, controllerType);
            }
        }
        catch (StructureMapException)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(
                ObjectFactory.WhatDoIHave());
            throw;
        }

        return result;
    }
}

public AController(IServiceA serviceA)
{
    if (serviceA == null)
    {
        throw new Exception("IServiceA cannot be null");
    }
    _ServiceA = serviceA;
}

public ServiceA(IRepositoryA repository)
{
    if (repository == null)
    {
        throw new Exception(
            "the repository IRepositoryA cannot be null");
    }

    _Repository = repository;
}
```

Thanks for your help, please ask if it is not clear..

Comment: are you working following PRISM guidelines?

Comment: Just starting using silverlight amd MVVM, I saw Prism, but I intended to get into it in phase 2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Silverlight you should use a bootstrapper at composition root to wire up your entire object graph. It could be the Application class app.xml.cs and look similar to

```
public partial class App : Application
{
   private void Application_Startup(object sender, StartupEventArgs e)
   {
       Bootstrapper bootstrapper = new Bootstrapper();
       bootstrapper.Run();
   }
}
```

In general this should be sufficant but if you need a separate Factory class for your views, take a look at 
[Keeping the DI-container usage in the composition root in Silverlight and MVVM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2190676/keeping-the-di-container-usage-in-the-composition-root-in-silverlight-and-mvvm).

Comment: sorry If I take time to validate  your answer. But I need it to explore this way (especially the link...)

Answer (score 1):

For Silverlight you may use PRISM framework with custom IoC container.

Comment: Ninject also. My question was more where to centralize all references to my IOC container in silverlight. as detailed in my question, in MVC3, you have the DefaultControllerFactory. Otherwise I will use a static class to wrap the call to the IOC Container...

Answer (score 0):

Autofac has built in support for silverlight: http://weblogs.asp.net/dwahlin/archive/2010/01/03/using-autofac-as-an-ioc-container-in-silverlight-applications.aspx

Comment: Ninject also. My question was more where to centralize all references to my IOC container in silverlight. as detailed in my question, in MVC3, you have the DefaultControllerFactory. Otherwise I will use a static class to wrap the call to the IOC Container...